# Python: Use a For Loop to Create a Dictionary of XML Nested Tags for Undetermined Level of Nesting

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, nested, elementtree

I'm parsing many thousands of XML files, each with generally more than 200 tags that can vary quite a lot. To compare them, I want to be able to gather their structures, and then compare each tier of nested tags between the various files.

Nested dictionaries seem to be the way to go, and this code is cumbersome, but it works, for each level of nesting I find and use.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

strip_ns = lambda xx: str(xx).split('}', 1)[1]
tree = ET.parse('xmlpath.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


tierdict = {}
for tier1 in root:
    tier1var = strip_ns(tier1.tag)
    tierdict[tier1var] = {}
    for tier2 in tier1:
        tier2var = strip_ns(tier2.tag)
        tierdict[tier1var][tier2var] = {}
        for tier3 in tier2:
            tier3var = strip_ns(tier3.tag)
            tierdict[tier1var][tier2var][tier3var] = {}
            for tier4 in tier3:
                tier4var = strip_ns(tier4.tag)
                tierdict[tier1var][tier2var][tier3var][tier4var] = {}
```

However:

- 1) Is there more efficient way to code this as is, especially when it comes to identifying each "tier"/level of nesting?
- 2) More importantly, is there a way to do this kind of looping for nesting of unknown depth? Some of these files might go 10 or 20 nestings deep, and I have no way to check them by hand.

Comment: can you add samples of the nested structures in your files?

Comment: This could work with any XML file, I think.
Here's a decent example of deep nesting:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056412/parsing-xml-for-deeply-nested-data

Comment: Perhaps the xmltodict library can help: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Comment: When you compare them, what are you looking at - differences in the structures, file changes?

Comment: I'm trying to compare different naming schemes for the tags. So, for example, the same kind of information could be stored in two different files with two different tags called `<FinancialGroup>` and `<FinancialGrp>` or for have any number of other differences in the naming. Also, some files might have certain kinds of information and their corresponding tags in the first place, and some others might be missing some portion of those.